# An Analytical method for resolving $\frac{n}{2^n} < \frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm looking for an analytical method for finding the smallest non-negative value of an integer $n$ such that $$\frac{n}{2^n}<\frac{1}{n^2}$$

My instinct is to manipulate the inequality into the form $$\frac{3}{\ln(2)} <\frac{n}{\ln(n)}$$but I'm now drawing an enormous blank.  Is there anything I can do from here?

Comment: What is $n$ -- integer? real number?

Comment: Oops.  It's an integer.

Comment: There is no smallest value of $n$ as the inequality is valid for all negative $n$.

Comment: You can use the LambertW function

Comment: If $n$ is a positive integer then the smallest is $n=1$.

Comment: It's a lot easier to deal with $n^3<2^n$ instead of $\tfrac3{\ln 2}< \tfrac n{\ln n}$, I think. You can find that solution mentally.

Comment: It is like @Lozenges said... The solution set for the inequality is $\{1\} \cup \{n\in \mathbb{N}: n \ge 10\}$, so the smallest natural number for which the inequality is satisfied is in fact $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the smallest integer $n>0$ at which this holds is $n=1$, but I assume you want to find the smallest $n_0>0$ such that the inequality holds for all $n \geqslant n_0$. By manipulating the expression, we equivalently want to solve for the inequality $2^n > n^3$. So we want the smallest integer $n_0$ such that $2^n > n^3$ for all $n\geqslant n_0$. The following solution does not solve for the smallest such $n_0$ by solving an algebraic equation (perhaps what the OP had in mind by "analytic") but it does provide a way to prove that such an $n_0$ works.

Consider the (differentiable) function $f(x) = 2^x - x^3$. We have $f(10) > 0$, and we claim that $f'(x) > 0$ if $x\geqslant 10$. This will show that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing for $x\geqslant 10$, so the inequality we want to show is true for all $n \geqslant n_0 = 10$, and that $10$ is the first $n_0$ for which this is true is a simple check.

Assume $x \geqslant 10$. Then, since $\ln(2)>1$ and $-3x^2 > -10x^2$,
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \ln(2)\cdot2^x-3x^2 \\
&> \ln(2)\cdot2^x-1000 \\
&>1\cdot 2^x - 1000 \\
&> 1\cdot 2^{10}-1000 \\
&= 24 > 0.
\end{align*}
Hence the claim.